# ASP.NET MVC authenticates and authorizes non-existent users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I'm using the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` Initializer so my database gets destroyed every time I start the application (at least I hope so). The funny thing is I still see myself as logged in. I get pass the `Authorize` attribute and can do dangerous stuff. This is probably because of leftover cookies from previous testing.

Registration/login part of my app is the MVC 4 Internet Application template untouched. Shouldn't ASP.NET check the cookie values against users saved in the DB? `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` returns true and `WebSecurity.CurrentUserName` returns the name.
The only thing working as expected is `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` which returns -1. I'm a newbie so I can only guess this is because `UserId` isn't stored in the cookie and must be retrieved from the database.

Am I right? If so, does it mean I should always use `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` to determine whether a user is logged in? `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` seem pretty useless in that case. I can delete a user's account and he or she remains unaffected. What should be done differently if I am wrong?

Comment: I have to ask.  Does it really matter?  In production, how often will you be throwing away the database?  Never?  So what's the issue?  If you're worried, don't make the cookie persistent (remove any checkbox that keeps them logged in, and set false for persistent cookie).  Yes, you can delete them and if they are currently logged in they can still have access, but as soon as they close their browser they can't log in again.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a small window where if a user is deleted and they are still logged in that they can still access the site. Since most actions require a validate user id, you can simply throw an excpetion and log the user out.

Normally the database does not get blown away on each build, so I'm guessing this is not a use case SimpleMembership was coded for. You can of  course check for this. I'll make another assumption that you are not closing your browser when you rebuild the site and deploy the new database. In a real world scenario these things just don't happen. The database is never blown away and the user id is never lost.

Generally once you've logged in the user, the user is not authenticated anytime after that (unless they have logged out, or the session has expired). That's the point of login. The authentication cookie is an indication that the authentication happened and was successful. The assumption going forward is the user has access to your site and is not reauthenticated.

Comment: It just seems a security flaw to me that (Simple)Membership doesn't query the database and blindly uses username extracted from the authentication cookie. What's that good for if the user may have already been deleted and since I need user id anyway?

Comment: @MattRicks Its an assumption that once you've been authenticated the account is valid. In all the systems I've worked on I've never seen a case where the user was logged in when an account was deleted. Not to say it can't happen, it's an edge case. Why is it a bad thing to use the user id from the auth cookie? The auth cookie is encrypted specific to that machine. It trusts the cookie, because it set the cookie.

Comment: Well I think the IsAuthenticated method should work like this:
1. check the cookie values
2. query the DB for user id
3. return whether the user has the auth cookie AND exists.

It looks like I'm the only one having problem with the current version. :)

Comment: Fortunately, the WebSecurity class has other methods and properties more suitable for my application. I just have to replace the "problematic" default authentication call with the right one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to realiably check whether a user has not been deleted, you just **have** to consult the database.

Note that users and administrators work concurrently. This means that a user can be deleted just a second after he has been authenticated. A cookie can be then even one or two seconds old (!) and the user could probably have been just deleted.

In a most pessimistic scenario, a user types a valid username and password and is succesfully logged in and get the "sorry, your account has been deleted" just one request later (because the account has really just been deleted).

Answer (score 1):

As long as the authentication session remains open (i.e. browser now closed), the session cookie remains active and MVC assumes that the user is still valid.

Remove the cookie by using `FormsAuthentication.LogOff()` if the user is authenticated (`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true`) and there's no valid user in UserTable (`WebSecurity.CurrentUserId == -1`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but solved it by specifying the required role(s) in the Authorize attribute. As soon as you do this, it start getting to the database and fails with the "user does not exist" error, which is what you want.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Customer")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

In normal case adding `Session.Abandon();` to to your `LogOff` action in `AccountController` would do the job of clearing session:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

So I think you can try adding `Session.Abandon();` in init code, where you use `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` to clear session each time.

Answer (score 0):

- The ticket issuing time is usually encrypted within the authentication cookie then you can use it to require re-authentication to sensitive areas (inbox/billing etc.) if more than X time passed since login.
- If you insist on invalidating all current auth tickets upon application changes (i.e database/configuration) you can change this settings in your `web.config`:

  ```
  <machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="" />
  ```